# Is there anything called "quality of PhD"?

Tags: phd, degree

I heard the term "Quality of a PhD" many times.

People says that "Quality of a PhD" determines the usefulness of a PhD degree and the employ-ability of a PhD graduate.

My questions are:

1. Is there anything called "Quality of a PhD"?
2. What factors determine the "Quality of a PhD" degree? Is it topic, is it the supervisor, school, country, or anything else?
3. Is it possible for a person to get a PhD degree in a school/country "X" which is not recognized in a school/country "Y"?

Comment: Have you searched on this site? (Im not the downvoter). Here is plenty of info.

Comment: There is all that "cum laude" thing, you know.

Comment: @OlegLobachev but that term does not exist everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but it can be pretty nebulous. It is a mixture of many things. Some universities are known to turn out well qualified people. Others are less known and may, in fact, not do as well, having a faculty that is not as well connected to current research trends in some field. But it depends on the field, and on the advisor, and on the dissertation, and so on.

I doubt that country alone is a huge factor except that countries with a smaller population have fewer universities and so fewer top universities.

As to your last question, if you don't make country the determining factor then sure. Some graduates from place X will find it hard to get recognized in place Y. But others will do fine.

It is even the case that some laser known universities have really great research programs in some fields because of a few highly educated and dedicated faculty.

However, there are some programs in some places that don't really measure up to the norm. They grant doctorates in name only.

And beyond that, some doctorates that would be recognized in some field won't be in a closely related field. For example, some doctorates have a purely clinical focus which doesn't really prepare one for a position requiring grounding in research and in theory. This may be the most important basis of what you have "heard".

---

But maybe an example. My degree in math is from not-Harvard. A degree from Harvard might be considered higher quality. But then, my major professor was pretty renowned. And my dissertation was considered pretty awesome (by about half a dozen people in the world). So, what did the Harvard graduate do and who did they work with? And, and, and.

Ephemeral things are hard to weigh, obviously.